# Show different text content on same activity

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I am working on first aid app, now on main activity I have a list of around 40 diseases, when clicked on any item, it moves to next activity showing different content related to that disease. Now my question is, will I make 40 different activities for each disease, or if not then how to make a single activity that will show different content according to clicked disease, and how will I style that text content, because each content may contain different bullets, heading, length of text can be different for each disease.

Comment: You could use fragments instead of activities. If the content for each disease is not too much, you can also use Expandable ListView.

Comment: sir there is a lot of content related to each disease ant different content content contains different headings, bullets and description paragraphs...
how to manage all this in a single text view?

Comment: You could create HTML files for your articles and then display them in a WebView inside your activity.

Answer (score 2):

One activity and when you start it in the intent send also the text images styles or whatever you need

```
Intent diseaseIntent = new Intent(this, DiseaseActivity.class)
diseaseIntent.putStringExtra("key", textOfDisease);
startActivity(diseaseIntent);
```

and in DiseaseActivity's onCreate use

```
String textOfDisease = getIntent().getStringExtra("key", "value if string extra is null");
yourTextView.setText(textOfDisease);
```

you can add more fields to to intent here is the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
Good luck

Comment: thanku  sir, but where i will store the content of each disease?
in any string-array?
and how will i apply styles like bullets and headings in the content

Comment: String array could work and you can use HTML string and parse it as needed use the HTML class 
or just add some extra fields for styles